# What does dqAIC mean in r?

Tags: r, statistics

i am using the IC.test formula to compare models but don't know how to interpret it

```
    dqAIC df
DM7  0.0  20
DM1 65.7  17
DM2 65.7  17
DM3 65.7  17
DM4 67.8  7 
DM5 88.2  11
DM6   NA  23
```

This is the formula i used

```
testIC.D <- ICtab(DM1, DM2, DM3, DM4, DM5, DM6, DM7, type="qAIC")
testIC.D
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which package are you using that provides the `ICtab` function? That should be a part of the code you include in your question. You can probably answer your own question by using `?ICtab` to look at the documentation for the function. There is a section in the documentation that tells you the value returned by the function. Also please remember to use complete minimal code in future posts by following these suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.